# iPhone new GUI: Where is the checkbox next to the .a files?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm trying to import an .xcodeproj. I dragged-dropped the .xcodeproj into my project and then in the old Xcode GUI if I clicked on it, I would see a list with .a files on the right, which had checkboxes next to them.

My problem should be solved, once I click a checkbox next to one of these .a files.

Does anyone know how can I do this in the new Xcode GUI ??

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to make a dependent project? If you need to add a library you can directly drag-n-drop the library to your project to link against it.